# How do I keep a JFormattedTextField in non-overwrite mode?

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield, overwrite

I have a problem with JFormattedTextField, namely keeping it in non-overwriting mode. I found out how to set it to non-overwriting, namely with setOverwriteMode(false).

However, although this function lets me type in the field without overwriting, when focus is lost and I re-enter the field, overWriteMode is on again!

Is there a way to keep overWriteMode false? I would prefer a solution which doesn't set it to false everytime I lose focus, but if that's the only possible solution, so be it.

This is what I've got now:

```
    DefaultFormatter format = new DefaultFormatter();
    format.setOverwriteMode(false);

    inputField = new JFormattedTextField();
    inputField.setValue("don't overwrite this!");
    inputField.setColumns(20);
    format.install(inputField);// This does the trick only the first time I enter the field!
```

I hope someone can help me!

**Solution, as proposed by Robin:**

```
    DefaultFormatter format = new DefaultFormatter();
    format.setOverwriteMode(false);

    inputField = new JFormattedTextField(format); // put the formatter in the constructor
    inputField.setValue("don't overtype this!");
    inputField.setColumns(20);
```

Thanks for the help!
Regards

Comment: what is/are reall reason(s) for `DefaultFormatter#setOverwriteMode(false);`, what do you really need

Comment: Sidenote: normally you pass the formatter in the constructor of the `JFormattedTextField` instead of installing it manually. This is also documented in the javadoc of the `install` method

Comment: @mKorbel: using that function seems to be in the right direction, but it doesn't get me there, since it only works once. What I need is for the field to stay in non-overwriting mode. Perhaps `setOverWriteMode(..)` isn't adequate at all, but I do not know that yet.

Comment: [did you read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultFormatter.html), because I think that there no reason to use that (and only to use) for scientics number format ....

Comment: @mKorbel : scientics number format? I just want strings!

Comment: @Tim Kuipers for `Plain Vanilla String` to use `DocumentFilter` with `Pattern` if changes stays inside JTextComponents, otherwise to look at `DocumnetListener`, `JFormattedTextField` ís evil and driving me crazy a few months

Comment: It works for now, so I will keep this solution. Thanks for the (probably better) solution, tho!

Answer (score 2):

shot to the dark, is there something that I missed

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

public class MaskFormatterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        format.setParseIntegerOnly(true);
        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
        formatter.setMaximum(1000);
        formatter.setMinimum(0.0);
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
        //formatter.setOverwriteMode(false);

        JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        tf.setColumns(10);
        tf.setValue(123456789.99);
        JFormattedTextField tf1 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        tf1.setValue(1234567890.99);
        JFormattedTextField tf2 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        tf2.setValue(1111.1111);
        JFormattedTextField tf3 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        tf3.setValue(-1111.1111);
        JFormattedTextField tf4 = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        tf4.setValue(-56);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 0));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(tf);
        frame.add(tf1);
        frame.add(tf2);
        frame.add(tf3);
        frame.add(tf4);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean to say by this 'Answer', but when I compile your code, I cannot enter any text at all. This was not helpful.

Comment: could or couldn't be works, depends of `Formatter` used for `JFormattedTextField`, btw this one of `Funny Bugs`, do you want another 3-4, no idea from you describtion, in most times request `invokeLater()`, becasue there is probably the `strange traffic` (reall there isn't some) betweens view an model, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Tim Kuipers have to wait, maybe there is `dirty` hack, maybe not

Comment: @Catalina Island for example, I'm glad that required only one zero after decimal separator :-), bump, anyway, thank you ........

Comment: @CatalinaIsland: Good catch on autoboxing.